# Bootstrap 3 - Customise Device Width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and the online customise tool - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ - to set specific device widths but the CSS in the package I download seems to be missing any of the grid system.

I'm including the bootstrap.css file, and here's my HTML.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span9">
                        a
                    </div>
                    <div id="dont" class="span3">
                        a
                    </div>
                    <div id="dont" class="span3">
                        a
                    </div>
                    <div id="dont" class="span3">
                        a
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                right sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid system is really different now. The span-* classes comes from bootstrap 2.
You have to use now:

- .col-xs-* (Phones (<768px)
- .col-sm-* (≥768px)
- .col-md-* Desktops (≥992px)
- .col-lg-* (≥1200px).

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3 don't have classes like a "span*", read the [Grid Documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the correct 'media queries breakpoints'? If you believe the Zip is wrong, check it with an Merge/Diff-Tool.